# Chinese remainder theorem and the value of moduli

Tags: discrete-mathematics, chinese-remainder-theorem

When we prove the Chinese  Remainder Theorem, we construct for the system of linear congruences
$$ x \equiv a_1 \mod m_1,\; ... \;,x \equiv a_n \mod m_n$$
we have :
$$M_k = \frac{m}{m_k} $$
**where m = $m_1.m_2...m_n$**
and
we construct $x=a_1M_1y_1+...+a_nM_ny_n$, where all $y_k$ are inverse of respective $M_k$ in $m_k$ modulo world.

Now, I get why this construction is being done for a simultaneous solution, but, there's a confusion of how **m** is obtained.

My reasoning is as:
if $x\equiv y\mod\ m$ is not the same as $x\equiv y\mod\ m_k$ for all  positive integers $k$.
then,
**why is x obtained in a $\mod m$ world? where $m = m_1.m_2...m_n$
why is $x$ in LCM  of  all  the  moduli?
i.e. why is $x \equiv a_1M_1y_1+...+a_nM_ny_n \mod m$**?

Answer (score 1):

I don't want to drown you in a sea of notation. So I will show you a detailed example and let you work out the general case for yourself.

Note that $5400 = 2^3 \times 5^2 \times 3^3$. So, according to the CRT, there exists an isomorphism 
$$f : \mathbb Z_{5400} \to \mathbb Z_8 \oplus \mathbb Z_{25} \oplus \mathbb Z_{27}$$.

The whole idea is that, if $f(x)=(x_1,x_2,x_3)$, then we should expect that

\begin{align}
   x &\equiv x_1 \pmod {\phantom{2}8}  \\
   x &\equiv x_2 \pmod {25} \\
   x &\equiv x_3 \pmod {27} 
\end{align}

This suggest the interesting identity $f(x)=(x,x,x)$; which makes it very easy to prove that $f$ is a homomorphism. Because $|\mathbb Z_{5400}| = |\mathbb Z_8 \oplus \mathbb Z_{25} \oplus \mathbb Z_{27}| = 5400$, we need only show that $f$ is one-to-one or onto in order to prove that $f$ is bijective, and hence an isomorphism.

Let's try to show that $f$ is onto. We define
\begin{align}
   e_1 &= (1,0,0) \\
   e_2 &= (0,1,0) \\
   e_3 &= (0,0,1)
\end{align}

Then $(x_1, x_2, x_3) = x_1e_1+x_2e_2+x_3e_3$. If we could find 
$m_1, m_2,m_3 \in \mathbb Z_{5400}$ such that

\begin{align}
   f(m_1) &= e_1 \\
   f(m_2) &= e_2 \\
   f(m_3) &= e_3
\end{align}

Now we finally get down to your question. How do we find the values of the $m_is$?

First $m_1$ must satisfy

\begin{align}
   m_1 &\equiv 1 \pmod {\phantom{2}8} \\
   m_1 &\equiv 0 \pmod {25} \\
   m_1 &\equiv 0 \pmod {27}
\end{align}

If we let 
$m_1 \equiv 25 \cdot 27 \cdot \alpha
     \equiv \left(\dfrac{5400}{8}\right) \alpha
     \equiv 675 \alpha \pmod{5400}$,

then we see immediately that $m_1 \equiv 0 \pmod {25}$ and $m_1 \equiv 0 \pmod {27}$.
We still need to make one more equivalence true.

\begin{align}
   m_1 &\equiv 1 \pmod 8 \\
   675\alpha &\equiv 1 \pmod 8 \\
   3\alpha &\equiv 1 \pmod 8 \\
   \alpha &\equiv 3 \pmod 8 \\
\hline
   m_1 &\equiv 3\cdot 675 \pmod{5400} \\
   m_1 &\equiv 2025 \pmod{5400}
\end{align}

Next we let 
$m_2 \equiv 8 \cdot 27 \cdot \alpha
     \equiv \left(\dfrac{5400}{25}\right) \alpha
     \equiv 216 \alpha \pmod{5400}$

So $m_2 \equiv 0 \pmod {8}$ and $m_2 \equiv 0 \pmod {27}$.

\begin{align}
   m_2 &\equiv 1 \pmod{25} \\
   216\alpha &\equiv 1 \pmod{25} \\
   16\alpha &\equiv 1 \pmod{25}\\
   \alpha &\equiv 11 \pmod 8 \\
\hline
   m_2 &\equiv 216\cdot 11 \pmod{5400} \\
   m_2 &\equiv 2376 \pmod{5400}
\end{align}

Finally, we let 
$m_3 \equiv 8 \cdot 25 \cdot \alpha
     \equiv \left(\dfrac{5400}{27}\right) \alpha
     \equiv 200 \alpha \pmod{5400}$

So $m_3 \equiv 0 \pmod {8}$ and $m_2 \equiv 0 \pmod {25}$.

\begin{align}
   m_3 &\equiv 1 \pmod{27} \\
   200\alpha &\equiv 1 \pmod{27} \\
   11\alpha &\equiv 1 \pmod{27}\\
   \alpha &\equiv 5 \pmod{27} \\
\hline
   m_3 &\equiv 200\cdot 5 \pmod{5400} \\
   m_3 &\equiv 1000 \pmod{5400}
\end{align}

We have not only shown now that $f$ is onto, we have also shown that
$$f^{-1}(x,y,z) \equiv 2025x + 2376y + 1000z \pmod{5400}$$

This should be enough information to see what is required of a real proof of CRT. Can you see why it was necessary for $8, 25$, and $27$ to be pairwise prime?